# subprocess to get the response of a command gives issues

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

```
>>>import subprocess        
>>>pipe= subprocess.Popen(["ls",'/etc/uu'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>>ls: cannot access /etc/uu: No such file or directory

>>>
```

Have executed the above command using subprocess, but after executed the prompt doesnt come, it requires an enter to come back on prompt. Could some one please help on this ?

Comment: What do you mean "the prompt doesn't come"?  By the way, if your real task is to "ls" some files, better to do it using Python directly (e.g. `os.stat()`.

Comment: Try `subprocess.Popen(["ls",'/etc/uu'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)`. It opens a shell process and because of error it keeps running there. So `shell=False` will get you the prompt back, if that is what you want.

Comment: i mean in the above code when i hit enter after 2nd line, i dont get the >>>. to get the >>> i need to provide Enter to get the <<< (4th line).

Answer (score 0):

You do get a prompt, what you are seeing is the subprocess outputs to `stderr` which writes over it.

You first enter the command

```
>>>import subprocess        
>>>pipe= subprocess.Popen(["ls",'/etc/uu'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

after hitting enter you get a prompt

```
>>>
```

Then the stderr of the command printed `ls: cannot access /etc/uu: No such file or directory\n` to the console which left

```
>>>ls: cannot access /etc/uu: No such file or directory
```

At this point the prompt will still except input. Pressing return of course outputs `\n>>>` like it normally would.

You can redirect the `stderr` to `stdout` if you want to stop it displaying on the prompt like this with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` in the call to `Popen`.

Answer (score 0):

What has happened is that the `>>>` has been deleted, just like it would if you were to type `print 5+5` and the result would not have `>>>` after it.

To prove that the "prompt" is still there:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> pipe = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/foo/bar/zoo'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> ls: cannot access /foo/bar/zoo: No such file or directory
print 5+5 # see how this works?
10
>>>
```